# Facebook send and like boxes getting cut

Tags: html, css, facebook

does anyone know what is causing my like and send boxes to cut off abruptly? You can try and of said buttons on [my site](http://easydiablo3.com/) to see what I mean.

**Edit:** Here is what it looks like in IE, Firefox, and Chrome:
[image]

Comment: In Chrome it looks ok to me. In which browser is it making problem?

Comment: i tested in chrome and it did not look right. Are you using *absolute* positioning at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS file http://easydiablo3.com/themes/MyTheme/css.axd?name=style2.5.0.6.css you have the following CSS:

```
.postSocialButtons .fb_ltr {
     width: 126px !important;
}
```

The `!important` appended at the end of your width declaration is causing this width to override all of your other widths and giving the appearance that the send box is getting cut off.

This is a perfect example as to why you should be mindful when using the `!important` declaration.

Comment: Thanks man. I actually had put that in a long time ago to remove some extra padding that was being generated by the control, not knowing I broke the popup window too.